# Is いう supposed to sound a little like ゆ

Tags: pronunciation

when hearing いう, it sounds a little like ゆ,　like the う sounds like it said a little y before is. Am I hearing it correct. I feel like is sounds like いyう or something like that

Answer (score 2):

いう *is* written いう but pronounced (indistinguishably from, as far as I know) ゆう. Make sure to pronounce it for two moras (and not one mora, as if it was written ゆ).

Comment: That's what I learned and the NHK 日本語発音アクセント辞典 (1966) also lists 言う under ユウ